# Change the positive number to negative number in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, converters, negative-number, arrayobject

Given `array` of `object` in database:

```
detail : [ 
       0: {
            Code: "Code 1",
            Price: "1.00",
            IncTaxPrice: "1.20",
            Tax:"0.20",
  
          },           

       1: {
            Code: "Code 2",
            Price: "9.00",
            IncTaxPrice: "9.20",
            Tax:"0.20",
  
          }
]
```

Output i want with key and value negative (for eg)

```
[
  {
    Code: "Code 1",
    Price: "-1.00",
    IncTaxPrice: "-1.20",
    Tax: "-0.20",
  },
  {
    Code: "Code 2",
    Price: "-9.00",
    IncTaxPrice: "-9.20",
    Tax: "-0.20",
  },
];
```

I tried with the `map`, filter `function` but it gave an error I guess I am missing something.
After it filters properly I will use `-Math.abs()`, to convert `positive` to `negative`.

```
let final = detail.map(a => Object.values(a).filter(v => typeof v === 'number'))
```

the element like `price`,`tax` are something like 8 different `elements` of `numbers` and `amounts`.

Comment: "_it gave an error_" What error? Notice that the syntax of `detail` is invalid.

Comment: There are no number values in your array objects. Only string values.

Comment: @Teemu  it displays like this

  final [
  [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
  [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
  [], [], [], []
]

Comment: `Object.values()` returns a copy of the values. Changing them doesn't change the content of the object.

Comment: If this financial, be careful using `Math.abs()`,  Just do `var newvalue = -oldvalue` to flip the sign instead.  This is because in theory a price could be negative, aka a refund.

Comment: @Andreas in addition `typof` will return `"string"` for each of these, because none of them are numbers.

Comment: ```filter(v => !isNaN(Number(v))``` you should change your filter, because all numbers are a string.

Comment: I understand it you are right @VLAZ but  i can't change the type of price because in database it is like this.

Comment: @ikhvjs it might be a problem if there is any Code field with something that converts to a number. Given the structure is known, I'd just explicitly check for the keys that have numeric values.

Comment: @VLAZ, you are right. it would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @VLAZ suggestion in the comment. I think you can filter by the key using Object.keys().

**Example below:**

```js
const detail = [
  {
    Code: "Code 1",
    Price: "1.00",
    IncTaxPrice: "1.20",
    Tax: "0.20",
  },
  {
    Code: "Code 2",
    Price: "9.00",
    IncTaxPrice: "9.20",
    Tax: "-0.20",
  },
];

let final = detail.map(x => ({
  Code: x.Code,
  Price: -Number(x.Price),
  IncTaxPrice: -Number(x.IncTaxPrice),
  Tax: -Number(x.Tax),
}));

console.log(final);
```

Comment: `-a[key])` is enough to flip the sign. The unary `-` will convert to number *and* flip the sign. If you want to be explicit, then `-Number(a[key])` is better on the off chance that `a[key]` is already negative. E.g., if it's `"-5"` then `"-" + "-5"` will be `"--5"` which converts to `NaN`

Comment: @VLAZ, wow.. once again Thanks for your reminder! I updated my answer as OP wants a negative value, I use Math.abs()

Comment: @ikhvjs  , actually i need output with key and value like 
`[
  {
    Code: "Code 1",
    Price: -1.00,
    IncTaxPrice: -1.20,
    Tax: -0.20,
  },
  {
    Code: "Code 2",
    Price: -9.00,
    IncTaxPrice: -9.20,
    Tax: -0.20,
  },
];`

Comment: For financial transactions, it's really a good idea to avoid `abs`,.  Doing `-Number(a[key])` like @VLAZ points out is much safer, and it's going to flip them to negative numbers, unless the price is negative, and in that case it will make them positive, keeping those negative is very likely going to cause issues..  And your example data with `9.00, 9.20, -0.20` is totally nonsensical.

Comment: @Harshu, I updated the answer but I cannot retrieve some numbers with 2 decimals. If you want to return an integer number or a number with 1 decimal, it would be a string instead.

Comment: @Keith, Thanks for your remind. I change the codes without Math.abs()

Comment: Just `Price: -price` is fine don't use the ternary you will just be making another abs.  I do a lots of work with financial data, I remember spending days trying to figure out how a z-reading, was not summing up with auxiliary reports, only to find some plonker had done abs on one of the reports.  Yes, in your example data that would make the `-0.20` into `+0.20` and that's indeed from a financial perspective is 100% correct.

Comment: @Keith, yes, makes sense.....I updated my answer to flip the sign only.

Comment: @Harshu, please read Keith comments above.

Comment: @Keith  thanks for your help I did like this but I thought if there are other ways or not because in this we need to create another array with all details, in my database, I am having more than 10 pairs of keys and values. Anyways thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your 0, 1 indexes in curly brackets as it is an array of objects. You can't just define it as you did because indexes 0 and 1 are not just numbers (fex. `[0,1,2]` is valid but not `[0:{code:...},1:{code:...}]` They are contining an object inside, so they are objects and you can't map if your array of objects is not properly defined as:
[{0:{code:..}},{1:{code:..}}.

Also using typeof filter wont' work because  all values are type string.

I would go like this:

```
let detail = [ {
       0: {
            Code: "Code 1",
            Price: "1.00",
            IncTaxPrice: "1.20",
            Tax:"0.20",
  
          }},           

              {1: {
            Code: "Code 2",
            Price: "9.00",
            IncTaxPrice: "9.20",
            Tax:"0.20",
  
          }}
]
detail.map(el=>{
        
            el[Object.keys(el)[0]]['Price']=(-parseFloat(el[Object.keys(el)[0]]['Price'])).toString()
                                                         
   el[Object.keys(el)[0]]['IncTaxPrice']=(-parseFloat(el[Object.keys(el)[0]]['IncTaxPrice'])).toString()
                                                         
    el[Object.keys(el)[0]]['Tax']=(-parseFloat(el[Object.keys(el)[0]]['Tax'])).toString()
                                                        
           return
         }
          )
```

Comment: The `[0: {` bit in the OP's question I believe is just how some debuggers show Arrays.